# React Native AsyncStorage not working - now what am I doing wrong?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

What am I leaving out here?
At this point I just want to see it write a value and retrieve a value.  By setting the variable "appType" I can see if it's working.  It is not because the initial value of "appType" is not changing.  I can tell this by which page is loading.  I need this information upfront to determine which page is to load first.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer }    from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator }   from '@react-navigation/stack';

import AsyncStorage  from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import SpMyPage      from './screens/s_mypg';
import UsMyPage      from './screens/u_mypg';
import UsRegPage     from './screens/u_regs';



function checkAsyncStorage(){
  var appType = '';

  const storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('random_time', '50000')
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  }

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('random_time')
      if(value !== null) {
        // value previously stored
        appType = 'S';
      }
      else {
        appType = 'U';  
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
      appType = 'U';
    }
  }

  return appType; 
}

function PreHomeScreen() {
  var appType = checkAsyncStorage();

  if (appType == 'S') {
    return <SpMyPage />;
  }
  else {
    if (appType == 'U') {
      return <UsMyPage />;
    }
    else {
      return <UsRegPage />;
    }  
  }
}


/* ************************************************************************** */

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <NavigationContainer>
    
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName = "PreHomeScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="PreHomeScreen" component={PreHomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SpMyPage" component={SpMyPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="UsMyPage" component={UsMyPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="UsRegPage" component={UsRegPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to import AsynStorage is

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Here's an example from the repo.
https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/master/example/examples/GetSetClear.js

Comment: I took the brackets off and cleaned up the line but still no go...

Comment: Can you save 50000 as a string? Also what is the exact error you are facing?

Comment: I set the number to a string.  No change.  It doesn't appear that my async methods are running at all.  Can I run them within that function like that?

Comment: I'm not sure if the function is even called. Have you tried confirming that?

Comment: The function checkAsyncStorage is being called because I can change the value of appType in it manually and the correct screen comes up on load.  but the async methods don't seem to be running.  I'm completely new to React Native so I'm coding this by examples and it looks like it should work.

Comment: I meant is storeData and getData even being called?

Comment: They don't appear to.  I don't think I can run async functions within non-async functions.  I'll have to mess with it some more today and do some more searches.

Answer (score 0):

My original goal was to use AsyncStorage.
I coded it the way the examples showed.

But, I found that apparently I don't need to have an "async function" wrapped around the AsyncStorage methods.  Hence no "await" needed either.  Not sure if this is going to cause a problem but for now it seems to work.

```
function checkAsyncStorage(){
  var appType = '';
  
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('random_time', '50000')
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }

    try {
      const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('random_time')
      if(value !== null) {
        // value previously stored
        appType = 'S';
      }
      else {
        appType = '';  
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
      appType = 'U';
    }

  return appType; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// The import statement should be like:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

// The function to retrieve previously stored data (In this example it's "userId")

```
retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
      const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
      if (userId != null) {
        console.log(userId);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
};
```

// The function to store data (In this example it's "userId")

```
storeData = async () => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', value);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```